# how to remove `psobject`s from one array that exist in another array

Tags: powershell

## Background:

The Dean of Students at the school I work at has asked me to import the daily attendance and class attendance into our SIS from the LMS. This was easy, until I realized that there is cross contamination. For example, if John's parents emailed to let the school know that John is sick on 10/24/2017. The Dean marked John as absent for the day, and then his teachers marked him absent in each of his classes. As a result, John has a daily attendance record on 10/24/2017 AND 6 class absence records for each of the classes he missed that day.

They won't change their process, so I need a way to remove Class absences from the import file for students that also have Daily Absences on the same date.

## Question:

I have two arrays of `PSObject`s containing objects with different attributes.

The objects in the Daily Attendance array, `$dailyRecords`, all have the attributes, `StudentID`, `Date`, `Type`, and `Description`.

The Class Attendance array, `$classRecords`, has objects have the same attributes as the first one, and `CourseID` and `SectionNo`, in addition.

I've tried a few ways to remove the extra class records from the `$classRecords` array:

1. `$classRecords | Where-Object { $_.Date, $_.StudentID -notin $dailyRecords}`, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38243796/664950), but that gave me all of the ~1600 class records.
2. I tried the following, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31745567/664950), but got no results (I think) the objects in the arrays reference different types...? Not sure. (I just used the following, I didn't include the `foreach` part. Maybe that was the issue... I'll try it tonight and update.)

   ```
   Compare-Object $classRecords $dailyRecords |
       Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -ne "=="} | 
       Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
   ```
3. I also tried a variation on #2:

   ```
   Compare-Object $classRecords $dailyRecords -Property Date, StudentID |
       Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -ne "=="}
   # I had to remove the last line, as InputObject was no longer defined.
   ```

   But that resulted in me losing all the other attributes that I need.
4. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892555/664950) results in what is closest to what I want to do, but I can't figure out how to modify it to my needs.

How do I remove the duplicated data from the class attendance without losing any information about the objects themselves?

Comment: Instead of removing from either, why not build a new hash table by student id from both tables and skipping if an entry already exists?

Comment: Alas, Daily attendance (e.g., John is sick and missed the whole day) is different than Class attendance (e.g., John had a headache in the health center and missed his math class, or John spent too long with his friends at lunch and was 10 minutes late to his next class). Merging the datasets would require converting Daily to Class, and I'd need to know which classes John missed on a given date (he has 7 in total, but only 6 meet on a given day), and then I would have to extend that to each of the students, as they all have different schedules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$dailyRecords = @(
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='1'; Date='10/22/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'}
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='1'; Date='10/23/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'}
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='1'; Date='10/24/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'}
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='2'; Date='10/24/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'}
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='3'; Date='10/23/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'}
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='3'; Date='10/24/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'}
)

$classRecords = @(
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='1'; Date='10/19/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'; CourseId='1'; SectionNum='1'}
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='1'; Date='10/23/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'; CourseId='2'; SectionNum='2'}
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='1'; Date='10/24/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'; CourseId='3'; SectionNum='3'}
[PSCustomObject]@{StudentId='4'; Date='10/24/2017'; Type='type data'; Description='desc data'; CourseId='1'; SectionNum='1'}
)

$attendanceRecords = @{}

foreach ($record in $dailyRecords)
{
    $key = $record.StudentId + ';' + $record.Date
    $attendanceRecords.Add($key, $record)
}

foreach ($record in $classRecords)
{
    $key = $record.StudentId + ';' + $record.Date
    if (-not $attendanceRecords.ContainsKey($key))
    {
        $tempRecord = [PSCustomObject]($record | Select-Object StudentId, Date, Type, Description)
        $attendanceRecords.Add($key, $tempRecord)
    }
}

$attendanceRecords.Values | Sort -Property StudentId, Date | ft
```

and give output:

```
StudentId Date       Type      Description
--------- ----       ----      -----------
1         10/19/2017 type data desc data  
1         10/22/2017 type data desc data  
1         10/23/2017 type data desc data  
1         10/24/2017 type data desc data  
2         10/24/2017 type data desc data  
3         10/23/2017 type data desc data  
3         10/24/2017 type data desc data  
4         10/24/2017 type data desc data
```

which is all the Daily and each Class which is not already in Daily per your original requirement.

Comment: This works great, and is significantly faster than the other options. I set the type attribute for all daily records to "daily", and class records to "class". For your last line: `$attendanceRecords.Values | where-object {$_.Type -eq "class" | select-object # all attributes except Type`. Should I edit my changes in, or do you want to? Does it make a difference?

Comment: @MatthewD, no need to edit as the answer is not all-inclusive and more of a guide for further refinements as your solution progresses.  Glad it was of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
$classrecords=@(
[pscustomobject]@{Date='2017-10-24';StudentID=1}, 
[pscustomobject]@{Date='2017-10-25';StudentID=2},
[pscustomobject]@{Date='2017-10-26';StudentID=3}
)


$dailyRecords=@(
[pscustomobject]@{Date='2017-10-24';StudentID=1}, 
[pscustomobject]@{Date='2017-10-23';StudentID=2},
[pscustomobject]@{Date='2017-10-26';StudentID=5}
)


$classrecords | % {$current=$_; $dailyRecords | % { if ($_.Date -eq $current.Date -and $_.StudentID -eq $current.StudentID) {$current}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ret = @()
foreach($classRecord in $classRecords)
{
    foreach($dailyRecord in $dailyRecords)
    {
        if($classRecord.CourseID -eq $dailyRecord.CourseID) # modify this to match your conditions
        {
          $obj = New-Object PsObject
          foreach($classProp in $classRecord.PsObject.Properties) # do this loop for $dailyRecord if you want those properties as well
          {
            $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $prop.Name -NotePropertyValue $prop.Value
          }
          $ret += $obj
        }
    }
}

# output the array
$ret
```

After that, you might have to filter the dupes out of `$ret`

Comment: Hmm....that should work. I'll try it (with the correct attributes) when I get back to my desk, and mark it correct if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewD I prefer to write the code in two loops because it is easier to visualize. You can one line this, but it looks gross

Comment: I would still assert this can be done in O(n) and not O(n^2).  If the set is small enough perhaps this is not a factor...

Comment: @KoryGill whew, your scaring me with your data structures knowledge.

Comment: @KoryGill, yes, that would be ideal, as I have 510 daily records and around 3500 class records for the first month or so of school... I guess I could add an attribute for type (class / daily), merge, remove duplicates from the merged version based on student id and date, and then use a `where` to separate them again based on the new `type` attribute... Is that the kind of thing you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
$classRecords | Where {$c = $_; $dailyRecords | Where {$_.StudentID -ne $c.StudentID -and $_.Date -ne $c.Date}}
```